# How to remove text above JSlider

Tags: java, swing

I have a [JSlider](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html) in my GUI that goes from 0 to 100. For some reason, there is text above the slider position that displays the current value of the slider and it follows my slider around.  I.e., if I move my slider halfway, "50" appears above where my slider currently is.  However, I can't figure out what that text field is called, all I know is its part of the slider.

I want to either remove it or be able to change it to something else, how would I do that?

Comment: What UI is the slider using?  `slider.getUIClassID()`.  My default UI doesn't show what you're talking about.  You might have to supply your own UI or override/subclass an existing one.

Comment: Yes, its weird, from what I can tell most sliders doesn't have it, which is why its so hard and obscure to figure out. My slider.getUIClassID() returns "SliderUI"

Comment: Sorry, try printing out `slider.getUI().getClass()`.  My bad.

Comment: slider.getUI().getClass() returns javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthSliderUI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would have just commented on Etaoin's answer, but I don't have the reputation for it yet.

At any rate, call this before instantiating the JSlider:

```
UIManager.put("Slider.paintValue", false);
```

Note the capital 'V' in paintValue.

Furthermore, to print all of the fun things that are currently set by your UIManager, enter this code anywhere after the UIManager has been instantiated:

```
Iterator<Entry<Object, Object>> it = UIManager.getDefaults().entrySet().iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
    System.out.println(it.next());
```

Comment: See also this [article and utility](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/09/uimanager-defaults/).

Answer (score 3):

This bothered me on a project once, and I found the following workaround. Call this once before instantiating your JSlider -- I put it in a `static` block in my JPanel subclass:

```
UIManager.put("Slider.paintValue", false);
```

That'll take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a tooltip? Is it a little box that appears over the slider control and follows your mouse around if you grab the slider?
If this is the case, you can disable it simply by calling `setToolTipText( null )`, or override the text with `setToolTipText( "My Text" )`.

Answer (score -1):

As I see there is a [setLabelTable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setLabelTable%28java.util.Dictionary%29) method in JSlider with a Dictionary parameter.
I have not used it but I guess that if you set it to an empty dictionary (or empty labels for every possible value) then no labels will appear.

A better solution is the usage of [setPaintLabels](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JSlider.html#setPaintLabels%28boolean%29) with a `false` value.

Comment: nope, already tried it, the labelTable is used to mark the labels for the slider (the labels that go below a slider), it doesn't affect the value above the slider at all.

Comment: followup comment, setPaintLabels already defaults to false, and it affects the labels that you set with setLableTable, which is NOT what the slider value is. So it also doesn't work.  Like Mark said, those are for the tick mark labels, not the slider value I'm talking about.

Comment: Sorry, then, it is getting more interesting, upvote to the question.